# jQuery Not working as an external file. (works inline)

Tags: jquery, html

I have been trying to learn jQuery for a few weeks now but I have mainly been reading and watching tutorials.

I use Dreamweaver to create sites and am knowledgeable with HTML and CSS. Since I have started to use jQuery with dreamweaver it doesn't seem to work, even with very simple code. The coding works inline but just not externally.

In use of the .hide() function I am using the following code.

and the following jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('p').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        });
    });
```

I have wracked my brain to try and figure out why this isn't working but to no avail. Any help would be amazing.

Marc

Comment: You're not including `myfile.js` _then_ `jquery.js` are you? You can also try to `defer` the script include, but that's not guaranteed to work.

Comment: The snippet you've provided looks absolutely correct. There's likely a problem with one of your `<script>` tags - either the one to load jQuery or the one to load your script. Include the code to include your scripts, and say what errors you're currently getting.

Comment: Use your browsers ***debugger*** ... Half the questions on StackOverflow could be eliminated if people used debuggers ... `$/jQuery` is most likely `undefined` when you try to use it...

Answer (score 1):

your code looks good. Quite often it happens, that the path to the file is not correct. You can use the Firefox Extension Firebug for example to check if the file was loaded anyway. See under "Network" tab.

Best regards,
XL